# Asp.Net @OuputCache VarByCustom not keeping cache for 2 versions of 1 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

The output directive used within .apsx

```
<%@ OutputCache duration="60" VaryByParam="None" Location="Server" VaryByCustom="ListingPageCookieCache"%>
```

The override within global.asax.cs

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
    {
        if (arg == "ListingPageCookieCache")
        {                
            if (condition)//pseudo coded                    
                   return "ListingPageCookieCache" + "us";                   
               else 
                    return "ListingPageCookieCache" + "ca";
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }
```

My Questions / **explanations** to you:

- Why are we only able to cache 1 of the 2 possible outputs? **(loading `ca` over and over caches and retrieves output fine. If I were to load `us` the cache for `ca` is lost, but `us` is cached and retrieved fine, until someone else requests `ca` again.)**
- How can I cache both versions of this page - Without changing the location to ServerAndClient

@Kenneth - Update

For instance when I write this into the global.asax file

```
if (arg == "ListingPageCookieCache")
        {
            var page = context.CurrentHandler as ShowListing;
            if (page?.sub != null)
            {
                return "ListingPageCookieCache_" + page.sub.Type.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Then nothing is ever cached - but not because the string isn't set ....

If i change the above to use `context.PreviousHandler`, it caches the first time the page comes through - but not when the subscription change occurs from another request, so if US is loaded at first, then US is loaded for CA type sub's.

Comment: The behavior you're describing should not be happening, but I'm suspecting that you're mistaken. Could you share a bit more of the part where you do `if(condition) // pseudo coded`?

Comment: @Kenneth I'm accessing the database here as loading the pages public properties seem cached. Then building a string from all the concatenated values. And if the object isn't null [pseudo coded part] return string. Now I've verified that it is never null but I thought I'd check just in case anyway.